# How to cancel uploading file to azure blob storage while uploading in python?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

**problem statement:**
I have a function to upload files to azure storage. I need to cancel it while it is uploading.

**For example,** if the video is 10gb it took 20minutes to upload, but when the user cancels. the uploading should stop before totally uploaded to storage and without killing the task.

**The following is my upload function.**

```
blob_service = BlockBlobService(
        account_name=config['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'], account_key=config['AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'])
    try:
        blob_service.create_blob_from_path(
            config['CONTAINER_NAME'], filename, filepath)

        storage_blob_name = filename
        service = BaseBlobService(
            account_name=config['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'], account_key=config['AZURE_STORAGE_KEY'])
        permission = BlobPermissions(_str="rwdlac")
        token = service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(config['CONTAINER_NAME'], storage_blob_name,\
             permission=permission, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
        blobUrlWithSas = "https://{storage_account}.blob.core.windows.net/{storage_private_container}/{storage_blob_name}?{token}".format(
            storage_account=config['AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT'],
            storage_private_container=config['CONTAINER_NAME'],
            storage_blob_name=storage_blob_name,
            token=token
        )
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: I believe [the code in this link](https://gist.github.com/s1rc0/5ee709ef4bff653fcb52f2bd8c3bced6) will give you inspiration. Can use `task` to achieve.

Comment: Is there any progress?

Comment: No still i have same issue, problem is i use greenthreads (eventlet) for multitasking, in this case i can not find a way to use async.